# What happen with old objects after using spread operator?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

When we use spread operator, then the new obj will be created. So what happens with old objects, if we press button many times?

```
 const [name, setName] = useState({ first: "Name", last: 0 });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setName({ ...name, last: count });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Counter = {count}
        <button onClick={increment}>Set last name</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        {name.first} {name.last}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Lady question: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: First question: nothing

Comment: what happens with old objects, if we press button many times?